# How to make auto Complete list show after entering atleast 2 characters

Tags: jquery

As User types in the input i am searching the table and displaying results accordingly .

Could you please tell me , if the length of the entered input is at least greater than or equal to 2

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#filtertags').keyup(function(){
        $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
        var noElemtag = true;
        var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
        var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
        el = tr.find('label').filter(function(){
            return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
        }).closest('td');
        if (el.length >= 1) {
            noElemtag = false;
        }
        tr.not(el).fadeOut();
        el.fadeIn();
        if (noElemtag) {
            $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();
        }
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the length of your `input` element on `keyup` event and `show` or `hide` tags based on your value.

Updated code

```
$('#filtertags').keyup(function() {
    var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');//keep this outside as we have to show all elements on backspace
    if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
      $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
      var noElemtag = true;
      var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();

      el = tr.find('label').filter(function() {
        return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
      }).closest('td');
      if (el.length >= 1) {
        noElemtag = false;
      }
      tr.not(el).fadeOut();
      el.fadeIn();
      if (noElemtag) $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();
    } else {
      tr.fadeIn(); //show all if length does not match the required number of characters
      $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
    }
})
```

## [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e08o7uct/21/)

Comment: You don't mean this `if ($(this).val().length > 2) {` ;-) OP says equal or greater than

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Just a matter of `=` sign.. ;) Updated.. :)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrap your code looking for length of input field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#filtertags').keyup(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length > 1) { /* <- check length here */
                $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
                var noElemtag = true;
                var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
                var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
                el = tr.find('label').filter(function() {
                    return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
                }).closest('td');
                if (el.length >= 1) {
                    noElemtag = false;
                }
                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();
                if (noElemtag) $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();
            } else { /* otherwise show all */
                $('.ui-checkbox').parent().fadeIn();
                $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
            }
    })

});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/32/)

Comment: Thanks , but Incase i clear the input its not displaying all the values

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Call the search function only if the serach parameter is 2 or more character length.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#filtertags').keyup(function()
        {
        if($("#filtertags").val().length >= 2){
               $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
                var noElemtag = true;
                var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
                var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
                el = tr.find('label').filter(function()
                {
                        return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
                }).closest('td');
                if (el.length >= 1)
                {
                        noElemtag = false;
                }
                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();
                if (noElemtag) $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();

        }
        else {
            tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
            tr.fadeIn();
        }

        })
});
```

Comment: Thanks , but Incase i clear the input its not displaying all the values

Answer (score 0):

You can use the autocomplete widget of Jquery.

```
    $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
      source: foo,
      minLength: 1
    });

$( function() {
    var foo = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++"];
```

this will fire an function by 1 character.

Link to jquery autocomplete api:

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
                var TLen=0;
        $('#filtertags').keyup(function()
        {

           if($('#filtertags').val().length>=2)/*Find Text box length */
           {
                TLen= $('#filtertags').val().length;
                $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
                var noElemtag = true;
                var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
                var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
                el = tr.find('label').filter(function()
                {
                        return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
                }).closest('td');
                if (el.length >= 1)
                {
                        noElemtag = false;
                }
                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();
                if (noElemtag) $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();
                }
                else
                {                   
                    if(TLen>$('#filtertags').val().length)
                  {
                     $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
                var noElemtag = true;
                var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
                var tr = $('#tagstable tbody td');
                el = tr.find('label').filter(function()
                {
                        return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
                }).closest('td');
                if (el.length >= 1)
                {
                        noElemtag = false;
                }
                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();
                if (noElemtag) $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();
                }
                }
        })
});
```